# Close/Hide a dialog when area outside of dialog is clicked

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that has a pop-up dialog where a user can enter some information. I would like to have this dialog close or become hidden when any area in the application, other than the pop-up dialog, is clicked. This way the user can enter data as needed and only when the click outside of the pop-up dialog will it close.

I could use the `(mousleave)` event but I only want the pop-up dialog to be hidden when the user clicks somewhere in the main application (other than the pop-up dialog). In the image below that would mean anywhere in the blue area.

[image: example layout of application]

UPDATE: The biggesr difficulty for me is figuring out how to capture the click event in the main application (blue area) only.

Comment: Can we see how the dialog is displayed in the markup and/or code? Is it an Angular component?

Comment: The pop-up dialog is a separate component and I show it setting it's `ngClass='show` which is a BootStrap class

Comment: Can the dialog close itself, or is the parent responsible for closing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it wrong way for your component? The dialog should be open top of one fixed fullscreen element, like

```
<div class="overlayer" style="display: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); z-index: 9999" onclick="closeYourDialog()">
    <div class="your-dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If you not like the over layer you can set opacity = 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `ClickOutside` directive so that you can listen click events and check if its target is your target. You can check out [this page](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to create a custom directive.

In your directive, you can use `@HostListener()` to listen click events:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective{

    @Output()
    clickOutside: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event) {
        if(!this.elemRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        // Cliecked Outside
         this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }

    constructor(private elemRef: ElementRef) {
    }
}
```

Then in your template, you can use:

```
<div (clickOutside)="hidePopup()">...</div>
```

And in your component you can add/remove css classes or create/destroy the DOM element. In this case, I assume you defined your popup with `@ViewChild() popup: ElementRef` in your component:

```
hidePopup = () => {
    this.popup.nativeElement.classList.add("hidden");
    /*
     * Or you can do some other stuff here 
     */
}
```

Comment: A note after 3 years: You can consider using `Renderer2` service to manipulate the DOM instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use this dialog as a modal (may be a Bootstrap [modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)) which internally would be using a backdrop to listen and close the modal when you click outside.

If you want to do it through your own HTML, you can create a backdrop of your own and add a click event listener over the backdrop. The trick would be to prevent click events from bubbling up from your dialog.

Add a div for backdrop like:

```
<div *ngIf="customDialogOpen" class="customBackdrop" (click)="customDialogOpen = false">

<dialog-component *ngIf="customDialogOpen"></dialog-component>


.customBackdrop {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;  // lower than the z index of your dialog but higher than rest of the document
}
```

Now, whenever you open your dialog, set the `customDialogOpen` flag in your `.ts` file to true.

For all the `(click)` events from under the dialog, add something like:

```
<some-elemet  (click)="...(youFunctions); $event.stopPropagation()">
```

**Update**

My answer was adding the backdrop as a sibling, a better approach is given by @incNick, you can open the full dialog as a fixed element along with the backdrop, just add an extra div which stops propagation of all the click events.

```
<div class="customBackdrop" *ngIf="customDialogOpen" (click)="customDialogOpen = false">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
       <dialog-component></dialog-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: There is no need to add extra `stopPropagation()` in either this solution or the first solution if you have one outer div which handles the propagation.